# Asp.net MVC transporting ID to another page depending on Combox Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a WebForms programmer and I'm not really used to MVC, I am still learning, so this is my strungle.
I have 2 combo boxes that retrive values from an Entity Framework aka My database.
After selecting those values I want to click in a button that will go to another page with the final value from the database that I want, It's a bit complicate to explain like this so I will make an example:

This, in my head, would be the query:
Select Example1 from Table Where Example1.id_cat = Combobox1 and Example1.id_dif = Combobox2

This is what I want to do, I want to transport the value "Example1" to another page based on the combobox selected values.

This page that will have the value transported doesn't have a controller.

Comment: MVC framework uses controller to get the value from views. You can get your value in controller action and pass it using ViewBag

Answer (score 0):

You can set your value in the `Session` like so;

```
Session["variableName"] = value;
```

...during transfer or specify it as a request parameter when you redirect to your second page.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of sessionStorage in javascript to achieve the result you desire.

```
//You can do this on page1:
var cSV = "your combobox SelectedValue";

// Store Value into Session Storage
sessionStorage.setItem("cbSelectedValue", cSV);

DO this on page 2:
//Retrieve Transported Value from Session Storage
var transportedValue = sessionStorage.getItem("cbSelectedValue"); 

//Make use of retrieved value
$("div.TestDiv").html(transportedValue);
```